# "if" vs. "providing"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I wrote

> Then, if the rule classifies the node  as "content", the node's content is added to the content extracted so far; otherwise, the node's content is removed from the extracted content ***if*** it has been previously extracted as a portion of its parent's content.

Is my usage of "if" correct? can I write it with "providing"? what would be the difference?

> Then, if the rule classifies the node  as "content", the node's content is added to the content extracted so far; otherwise, the node's content is removed from the extracted content, **providing** it has been previously extracted as a portion of its parent's content.

Comment: On the first line, "rule classify" should be **rule classifies** (or **rules classify**, if there are multiple rules involved).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any difference between the two of them as **if** and **providing (that)/provided (that)** are synonymous in the context you provided and can be used interchangeably:

> provided that: [on the condition that](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/provided+that).

Comment: *On the condition that* is only one of many uses of *if*, however, so saying *if* and *provided that* are interchangeable is strong, if not altogether erroneous.

Comment: @choster, I mean in the provided context.

Comment: I think _provided_ works better in that context, if only for variety. There's a nested IF in either case, but the three syllable _pro•vi•ded_ gives the reader another moment to parse it correctly.